# jQuery Mobile - Do something on page load

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to do something every time a page loads. It's something that fixes the way the mobile site looks on different devices so it needs to happen on AJAX loads too.

At the moment, I've tried the traditional `$(function(){ /*...*/ });` approach but that only works on the first load, and not subsequent AJAX loads.

I've been looking for the right event to bind to but I'm failing pretty hard.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use JQuery to bind to each "page" (div's set with the `data-role=page` attribute) and use the `pageshow` event (there are some others as well: `pagebeforeshow`, `pagehide`, `pagebeforehide`).

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
    //Your code for each page load here
});
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/

Note: this answer was written for jQuery Mobile 1.0.1, see the documentation link above for more information.

Comment: pageshow has been deprecated in 1.4 and removed in 1.5.
Note: The triggering of this event is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0. It will no longer be triggered in 1.5.0.
The replacement for pageshow is the pagecontainer widget's pagecontainershow event. In jQuery Mobile 1.4.0, the two events are identical except for their name and the fact that pagecontainershow is triggered on the pagecontainer, whereas pageshow is triggered on the page.

Answer (score 5):

You can listen to the pageshow or pagecreate event and do your work there.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html