# Uncheck radiobutton in jQuery mobile on clicking it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I'm trying to make radiobuttons uncheckable, when a checked radiobutton is clicked, but i don't get it. Using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1. Already tried some examples from the previous versions, but all of them don't work.

the following works in JSFiddle, but not when i try it my browser.

JS:

```
var prev = {};
$('input[name*=radio-choice-]').click(function(){
    if (prev && prev.value == this.value) {
        $(this).prop('checked', !prev.status);
    }
    prev = {
        value: this.value,
        status: this.checked
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset id="hours" class="ui-grid-b" data-role="controlgroup"
                data-type="horizontal">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-1"
                            value="1"> <label for="radio-choice-1">1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-2"
                            value="2"> <label for="radio-choice-2">2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-3"
                            value="3"> <label for="radio-choice-3">3</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-4"
                            value="4"> <label for="radio-choice-4">4</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-5"
                            value="5"> <label for="radio-choice-5">5</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-6"
                            value="6"> <label for="radio-choice-6">6</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="minutes" class="ui-grid-b" data-role="controlgroup"
                data-type="horizontal">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-a" id="radio-choice-15"
                            value="15"> <label for="radio-choice-15">15</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-a" id="radio-choice-30"
                            value="30"> <label for="radio-choice-30">30</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height: 40px">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-a" id="radio-choice-45"
                            value="45"> <label for="radio-choice-45">45</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
       </div>

    </div>
```

**EDIT**: The Javascript works! Have to be added twice for different groups of radiobuttons (based on names).

**Hint** Code have to be added to
     $(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {*code hier*});
instead of 
     $(document).ready. 
The reason is explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455963/jquery-mobile-do-something-on-page-load)

Comment: after you `'check'` it add `.checkboxradio('refresh');`

Comment: It doesn't help also.

Comment: you have two sets of buttons, you want to disabled other group or same group?

Comment: I don't want to disable none of them. I want to have a possibility to uncheck any checked radiobutton.

Comment: yea i got it. you have a problem with the first `if` the object is empty. so you have to read all buttons and add them into an array and then read the array.

Comment: check this, it drove me crazy, but i managed finally to make it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/XbVL8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to Un-check ***checked*** radio button.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/XbVL8/)**

Create array of all radio buttons

```
var radios = [];

$('[type=radio]').each(function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var value = $(this).attr('value');
 var status = $(this).is(':checked');
 radios.push({
  'id': id,
   'value': value,
    'status': status
 });
});
```

Core code here...

```
$('[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
 var clicked = $(this);
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var status = $(this).is(':checked');
 var result = $.grep(radios, function (e) {
    return e.id == id;
 });
 var oldstatus = result[0].status;
 if (!oldstatus) {
  clicked.prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
 } else {
  clicked.prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
 }
 // Re-fill array to update changes..
 radios = [];
 $('[type=radio]').each(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  var status = $(this).is(':checked');
  radios.push({
   'id': id,
    'value': value,
     'status': status
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: The same problem as with my js. It works in jsfiddle but not in a browser.

Comment: Try this `$(document).on('click', '[type=radio]' , function () {`

Comment: @grekandco which browser are using? I just tested it live (not fiddle) on iPhone 4, Safari. It's working with no issues.

Comment: Was my fault! Thanks alot!

Comment: @grekandco great, glad i've been of help :)

Comment: My initial JS code does the job also, but with one issue. When a radiobutton is chosen in both of the groups you have to click twice to uncheck one of them. Your code doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @grekandco your code is simple, i guess it can be tweaked and would look better than mine :)

Comment: Will post here, if i can achive the same behaviour.